# Error: Permission denied to access property "getComputedStyle"

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo

I have this error when I open my application (with dojo) in a iframe from another application. This problem shows up only with Firefox (in Chrome it works).
**How can I resolve this problem?**

[image]

Comment: There is an open ticket about this issue: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been introduced on the latest dojo build (1.12.1).

We have reported already this issue to the dojo team, more info here:

https://github.com/dojo/dojo/commit/bfea978ffd6e7a0606ad677e457e7079e42a937d#commitcomment-20930838

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18976

Currently possible solutions are:

- Stick on dojo version 1.11.1 and wait dojo team to fix this issue.
- Overwrite `dom-style.js` and fix the issue yourself, here a solution could be to to reference `win.global.window` instead of `win.global.window.parent` at line 49 of `dom-style.js`.